# Вывод данных tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def get_range():
    for i in range(1, 100000):
        Label(root, text=i).pack()

Button(root, text='Click', command=get_range).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

При нажатии кнопки на форме происходит "зависание" до выполнения функции, однако необходимо выводить данные постепенно (после выполнения каждой итерации цикла).

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете использовать `цикл`, потому что он останавливает `mainloop`. 
Вы можете использовать `root.after` для вызова функции через `n` мс.

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_range(count):
    # изменить текст в метке
    label['text'] = count                     

    if count > 0:
        # Обратный отсчет через каждые 100 мс
        root.after(100, get_range, count-1)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.place(x=35, y=35)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Click', command=lambda i=100000: get_range(i)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно использовать и цикл, задачу я решил (ответ ниже)

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

root = Tk()

def get_range():
    for i in range(1, 100000):
        Label(root, text=i).pack()

t = threading.Thread(target=get_range)

Button(root, text='Click', command=t.start).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: вы пробовали изменять размеры окна или перемещать окно по экрану во время процесса ? Попробуйте закрыть окно во время работы программы.

Comment: запустите свой и мой пример параллельно и попробуйте изменять размеры окна или перемещать окно свое и мое. А потом закройте мое приложение и свое. Вы увидите разницу.